# Action Function nulling out values unless rerender is specified?

Tags: visualforce, rerender, actionfunction

I have the following part in my visualforce page:

```
<apex:form>
    <apex:actionFunction name="interestInShowConfirmed" action="{!interestInShowConfirmed}" />
    <apex:actionFunction name="registerInterest" action="{!openInterestedInShowPopUp}" >
        <apex:param name="chosenId" value=""/>
    </apex:actionFunction>
</apex:form>
```

The way this code works, is that the "RegisterInterest" action function is called when a user clicks on a button (E.X. the button would execute: registerInterest('123213213'); ) - The register interest action function then generates a pop up to the user confirming their selection. Finally, when the user chooses the yes button on the pop up, the interestInShowConfirmed action function is called. I am running into a strange issue where I seemingly need to specify a re render target for these action functions or variable changes are not saved to the view state.

For example, this line of code

```
openPositionIdChosenForInterest = system.CurrentPageReference().getParameters().get('chosenId');
```

will return the correct passed Id if i specify a re render target for the "registerInterest" action function, but will return null if i do not. Also, if i specify a re render target only on "registerInterest" and not on "interestInShowConfirmed" - any global varriables set by the registerInterest action function will be null when "interestInShowConfirmed" tries to access them.

I'm guessing there is something I do not understand about re rendering and the view state - could someone fill me in?

Edit:

Here is how the registerInterest function is called. It is a button inside a custom component included in the visualforce page:

```
<apex:commandButton value="{!cell['buttonLabel']}" onClick="{!cell['javascriptToCallOnClick']}('{!cell['argToStoreOnClick']}');" reRender="None" />
```

Also, if i don't include a rerender in this button, my action function is not called

Answer (score 1):

Not specifying `reRender` causes a POST request, while using `reRender` uses the AJAX library to perform the request. If you don't use a `reRender`, you *must* use the `assignTo` attribute of `apex:param`, as the parameters won't be posted (i.e. `currentPage().getParameters()` won't have any values).

The documentation is not particularly clear on this, but basically you need to either use `assignTo` or `reRender`; if you use neither, your parameters will be useless. This is true for other supported elements, like `apex:actionSupport`, when using parameters. You must use either attribute to have proper parameter support.

Comment: It appears that even with a assignTo property it does not work:

Ex. 
<apex:actionFunction name="registerInterest" action="{!openInterestedInShowPopUp}" >
            <apex:param name="chosenId" value="" assignTo="{!openPositionIdChosenForInterest}"/>
        </apex:actionFunction>

and the code behind:

if(openPositionIdChosenForInterest == null)
        {
            webpageUtilities.addError('Open Position Id not retrieved successfully from pop up', MAIN_PAGE_MESSAGES_ID);
            return;
        }

will unforuntately always trigger the message that the Id is null

Comment: @HansDonkersloot Hmm... I don't think I have enough context then. Maybe you could add more code in your question for context?

Comment: Admittedly this is a really complex page, which is likely why there is an issue somewhere here - I added the code for how the action function is invoked, hopefully that might explain some things

Comment: `The documentation is not particularly clear on this` - so true